# Doubtful serverfault migration

Tags: discussion, migration

Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167394/) really about "servers, networks or the administration of many machines"?

I can't understand how other questions that strictly not programming related (e.g. how to change some setting in Visual Studio) belong in SO, but not this question, that also focuses on how to set up a development tool/environment.

If it had been any 5 users voting to migrate, I wouldn't have brought this up, but since a moderator got involved, this seems to be some official policy whose reasoning I fail to grasp.

Answer (score 4):

The administration of server software, including PHP, belongs on Server Fault, because the typical php.ini file is touched by server administrators and not programmers.

On the other hand, a question about Visual Studio is a question that only a programmer would pose as VS is a programmer's tool, and does not relate to the server itself.

Comment: I was always curious about that. VS2008 UI just wonked out on me on our production server and I thought I'd ask a question, but I imagined that the question would better be asked on Super User (since it seems like a software thing, or summat like that, rather than a code thing).

Comment: The question was not about "touching php.ini". It was about setting up the web server so that multiple php.ini servers could be used. Apache is, in this context, a programmer's tool. I concede, however, it's not exactly the same as Visual Studio, as it's used both in development and production (yet I could use Apache with several virtual hosts for development and then have the websites it in production running in IIS with only one php.ini).